# Checking if words are within n space of one another (using nltk or otherwise) in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I have a list *file contents* that contains lists consisting of word tokens as its elements. I would like to create a function that takes two strings of length one and *size* as its input and returns instances where these two terms appear within *size* words of each other.

I have so far tokenized the words for each element in the list using nltk but I'm not sure where to go from here, could anyone refer me to an nltk method/python code that could do this?

Here is the what the function should look like

```
file_contents = [['man', 'once', 'upon', 'time', 'love', 'princess'], ['python', 'code', 'cool', 'uses, 'java'],['man', 'help', 'test', 'weird', 'love'], .............]


def check_words_within(string: word1, string:word2, int: size) -> list:
                    #how to implement?
```

`check_words_within('man','love', 4)` would return `[[man', 'once', 'upon', 'time', 'love'],['man', 'help', 'test', 'weird', 'love']]`

`check_words_within('man','upon', 1)` would return `[['man', 'once', 'upon']]`

`check_words_within('man','document',4)` would return `[]`

Does `nltk` have a function to help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a list of dicts to look up values from.*

```py
dat = [{ind: val for val, ind in enumerate(el)} for el in file_contents]

def foo(w1, w2, dist, f, fdat):
    arr = []
    for i, v in enumerate(fdat):
        i1 = v.get(w1)
        i2 = v.get(w2)
        if (i1 is not None) and (i2 is not None) and (i2 - i1 <= dist + 1):
            arr.append(f[i][i1:i2+1])
    return arr

foo("man", "upon", 1, file_contents, dat)
# [['man', 'once', 'upon']]
```

2. Create a class

```py
class Search:
    def __init__(self, words_list):
        self.__words_list = words_list
        self.__words_dict = self.__get_dict()        
    
    def __get_dict(self):
        d = {}
        for ind, arr in enumerate(self.__words_list):
            for pos, word in enumerate(arr):
                if not d.get(word):
                    d[word] = {}
                d[word][ind] = pos
        
        return d    
    
    def check_words_within(self, w1, w2, dist):
        arr = []
        if self.__words_dict.get(w1) and self.__words_dict.get(w2):
            wl_inds = self.__words_dict[w1].keys()
            for wl_ind in wl_inds:
                pos1 = self.__words_dict[w1][wl_ind]
                pos2 = self.__words_dict[w2].get(wl_ind, pos1 - 1)
                if (pos2 - pos1 > 0) and (pos2 - pos1 <= dist + 1):
                    arr.append(self.__words_list[wl_ind][pos1:pos2 + 1])
        
        return arr


foo = Search(file_contents)
foo.check_words_within("man", "love", 4)
# [['man', 'once', 'upon', 'time', 'love'],
#  ['man', 'help', 'test', 'weird', 'love']]
```